# when would I need to modify knowledge module in ODI?

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I have came across an ODI project and there seems to be a lot of user defined KMs and I don't understand why they were modified? Is there any particular scenario where existing KM doesn't work?

Comment: [Customising ODI Knowledge Modules](https://www.clearpeaks.com/customizing-odi-knowledge-modules/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of reasons for writing your own KM or modify the existing ones, for example:

- log in your own paths/tables;
- read metadata from flex fields (Metadata like: default values for some columns, base table name used for temporary tables, type of load: full/incremental etc);
- make different transformations/stage steps, different from the standard KM's;
- customize your CKM: make error table - where you see your rows in error, make correct result table and so on;
- for modifying KM you may have want to save the temporary tables with your own standard and so on.

The benefits of writing KM's is that the limit is your imagination (or almost). You can do plenty of stuff. The standard KM's are very good but there are some moments when you reach the limit with them and from there you should create your own.

Hope that this helps you.